# Do I need to know the algorithm's code to take advantage of inserters and move iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

**C++ Primer** (5th edition) gives a number of examples of achieving nice effects by passing an `inserter` or a `move iterator` instead of a regular iterator into an `std`'s generic algorithm.

I suspect, however, that being able to do this depends on inside knowledge of the workings of the algorithm, i.e. what precisely it does with its iterator arguments. This is even more severe with the `move inserter`, since we need to be sure that an object is not accessed after being moved from.

Is my suspicion justified? If it is, then how come the standard library takes an approach that requires the client (me) to know the internals of the provider (STL)?

Comment: All std containers provide certain guarantees but not others. This is all you need to know to use these features correctly.

Comment: `move_iterator` is an exception, you can have problems using it with some more complex algorithms. The inserters are just output iterators and should cause no surprises at all.

Comment: Although using `move_iterator` should not generally be a problem with algorithms that require InputIterators, because you can never assume you can read from an input iterator twice anyway (they are "single pass") so it doesn't matter if the object gets moved-from because the algorithm won't look at that object again. (This isn't always guaranteed, because some algorithms that work with InputIterators can be specialized to do something different for more refined types of iterator, and they might try to look at values twice ... as I said, `move_iterator` is a bit unusual).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the style of specification of the algorithms in the standard library.

Maybe you should start with  [Introduction to the Standard Template Library](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html) which explains that the whole point of the STL is that it is written in terms of generic [concepts](http://www.generic-programming.org/about/intro/concepts.php), not the specifics of what happens for every possible different argument type. This is the basis of [Generic Programming](http://www.generic-programming.org/).

If an algorithm that is specified to accept arguments that model the [OutputIterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/OutputIterator.html) concept then it means that the algorithm will only use operations that are valid for OutputIterators. The algorithm's specification will tell you what it does, e.g. [copy](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html) says:

> for every integer `n` from `0` to `last - first`, copy performs the assignment `*(result + n) = *(first + n)`

So this tells you that the algorithm will use the assignment operator.

A [`std::insert_iterator`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/insert_iterator.html) is a model of the OutputIterator concept, so you can use it with algorithms that work with OutputIterators. If the specification of the algorithm tells you it will assign to its OutputIterator arguments then you know what will happen because the specification of `std::insert_iterator` tells you what assignment means for `std::insert_iterator`. You don't need to look at the code of the algorithm to know this, because the description of the algorithms and the concepts named in its signature tell you which operations it is going to use (and they will only be ones supported by the concepts it requires).

In C++ today the concepts used by an algorithm are only stated informally, by naming template parameters to indicate the required concepts e.g.

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
ForwardIterator 
remove(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value);
```

By convention (and as specified in 25.1 [algorithms.general] paragraph 5) this means that the `remove` algorithm requires the type of its first two arguments to model the `ForwardIterator` concept.

In a future version of C++ it is expected that you will be able to state these requirements explicitly in the language e.g.

```
template<class FI, class T> requires Forward_iterator<FI>
FI 
remove(FI first, FI last, const T& value);
```

or equivalently:

```
template<Forward_iterator FI, class T>
FI
remove(FI first, FI last, const T& value);
```

Using this style of declaration will all the compiler to check that the arguments to the function really do meet all the requirements of a ForwardIterator, and reject the program otherwise.

Comment: Will **Effective STL** by Scott Meyers give me all the needed background as well or is it outdated?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg, it's a very good book about _using_ the standard library, but it isn't about generic programming so doesn't have all the _background_. If you're now OK with the idea of generic programming and the style of specification then I highly recommend Effective STL to learn how to use the containers and algorithms well.

Comment: I like to get solid background from a book. Is there a book about generic programming that you would recommend me to read prior to reading Effective STL?

Comment: _Generic Programming and the STL_ by Matt Austern is a good book on generic programming but isn't necessary or even particularly useful to read before _Effective STL_, they have different approaches and entirely different purposes. _Effective STL_ can be read without any background at all.

Answer (score 7):

No, you don't need to know the *implememtation* of any of the STL algorithms, as they have their Requirements in general specified in The International Standard.
For example, `std::remove()` is declared as:

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
ForwardIterator remove(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value);
```

And is described as follows:

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
ForwardIterator remove(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value);
```

> - **Requires:** The type of `*first` shall satisfy the `MoveAssignable` requirements (Table 22).
> - **Effects:** Eliminates all the elements referred to by iterator `i` in the range `[first,last)` for which the
>     following corresponding conditions hold: `*i == value`.
> - **Returns:** The end of the resulting range.
> - **Remarks:** Stable (17.6.5.7).
> - **Complexity:** Exactly `last - first` applications of the corresponding predicate.
> - **Note:** each element in the range `[ret,last)`, where `ret` is the returned value, has a valid but unspecified state, because the algorithms can eliminate elements by moving from elements that were originally in that range.

So all you ever *need* to know is The International Standard's paragraph about the algorithm, as it (and only it) specifies exactly *what* happens in the particular algorithm, no more, no less.

Besides, reading STL internals is a not a good idea, most of the time.

Comment: I do not see anything in the quoted documentation that spells out what will happen if I pass an `inserter` as `first`. Could you please go all the way with your example?

Comment: Inserters are output iterators, they do not meet the requirements of a forward iterator, so that's undefined behaviour, but that's not the inserter's fault. If you pass an inserter to an algorithm that expects output iterators it will work fine.

Comment: @nabijaczleweli, it might compile, the standard does not say it's ill-formed to violate the precondition, it is undefined behaviour (if your implementation checks it then it will fail to compile, which might only happen with certain debug mode or concept checks enabled).

Comment: @JonathanWakely OK. So, in this example it's easy -- the inserter iterators do not match the parameter type. I would very much appreciate example of an algorithm to which an `inserter` can be passed and about which the standard explicitly tells me what would happen when I pass an `inserter`.

Comment: The International Standard *never* explicitly says what happens when you pass an `insert_iterator` into an algorithm

Comment: @nabijaczleweli Then I am back to my question: how can I know this without looking at the source code?

Comment: By reading The International Standard? (or [cppereference](http://en.cppreference.org), which is like a simplified standard). For example `insert_iterator` is described like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator)

Comment: @nabijaczleweli But you just said that "The International Standard never explicitly says what happens when you pass an insert_iterator into an algorithm"! So, how will reading the Standard help?

Comment: An `insert_iterator` is an [OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) and has an [interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) like any other output iterator.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg By looking at the specifications of `insert_iterator`, you can guess what it's good at. Whether using a technique or another actually ends up performing better than the other, you can only tell through profiling.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg Example: `vector<one_gigabyte_of_data> vv(20); decltype(vv) vvv; copy(make_move_iterator(begin(vv)), make_move_iterator(end(vv)), back_inserter(vvv));` will move-insert all elements of `vv` into `vvv`

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg, _"how can I know this without looking at the source code?"_ I think you have missed the entire point of [Generic Programming](http://www.generic-programming.org/). See my answer.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg "Never explicitly tells you" is different than "never tells you".  The standard is often less than explicit.  It states what the requirements are on the iterators passed in explicitly (usually by iterator category).  It states what the properties that an `insert_iterator` fullfills (including iterator category).  If you understand iterator categories, you can work out what arguments can be populated by `insert_iterator`s.  Even if you read the implementation, it is free to *vary* between compiler versions, while the spec doesn't.